# I'm getting errors using braintree: ValidationErrorsCollection

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm developing an ecommecer and I'm using braintree as a payment method, some time ago there was no problem with this. but now it sometimes works without problems and there are times when I get this error in the backend: ReferenceError: error is not defined

[image]

```
exports.processPayment = (req, res) => {
    let nonceFromTheClient = req.body.paymentMethodNonce
    let amountFromTheClient = req.body.amount

    //charge
        
    //Backend Code
    let newTransaction = gateway.transaction.sale({
        amount: amountFromTheClient,
        paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, 
        options: {
            submitForSettlement: true
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
          if (result.success) {
            res.json(result);
          } else {
            console.log(result.errors)// error is pointed here in this line
          }
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
          });enter code here

}
```

Comment: Exactly what it says, "error is not defined" when you're calling`res.status(500).json(error)`. Perhaps you wanted to do `res.status(500).json(err)` inside the `catch` handler?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the first parameter **error** in the callback function

```
let newTransaction = gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: amountFromTheClient,
    paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, 
    options: {
        submitForSettlement: true
    }
}).then(function (error,result) {
      if (result.success) {
        res.json(result);
      } else {
        res.status(500).json(error); // error is pointed here in this line
      }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
```

[check this docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/node)

Comment: already put and error: ValidationErrorsCollection